# Connecting to database php (Hostgator)

Tags: php, mysql, database

Im getting errors when attempting to connect a simple script to my webhosting account. (Should i be using "localhost" here or the web host?)

```
//Setup server connection
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "dummy_dummy"; (CpanelName_DataBaseUserName)
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dummy_exo"; (CpanelName_DataBase)


//Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

All of the above information is completely correct (User, password, DB name)

> Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home1/name/public_html/index.php on line 38
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home1/name/public_html/index.php on line 38

Im fairly new to php so using a script to connect to an actual hosting account isnt going well for me

Comment: You seem to be connecting with `mysqli`, and then trying to query `mysql_query`. The `mysqli_` library does not work with `mysql_` functions - you should be using the former exclusively.

Comment: you need to consult their documentation. This isn't the place for questions like these

Comment: yeah... where does `mysql_` get into all this? your question/posted **code** does not support the problem.

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).